# Wall mounting a TV with flat / sideways studs?

Tags: walls, mounting, television

[image]

I'm trying to wall mount a TV and the stud finder shows that the studs are 4 inches wide. I found an access panel to get a peek behind the wall so I've included a picture, and this is what I see.

Can I safely mount a TV on these studs (covered by a sheet of drywall) and if not, what are my options?

Comment: how much does the TV weigh?

Comment: @jsotola It's a 55 inch, ‎37.3 pounds.

Comment: Is the mount wide enough that you can catch two of the upright studs? (I don't see fasteners on the sideways blocking, so it's possible/likely that it's only attached to the edges of the drywall, so not nothing but not guaranteed strong either.)

Comment: the TV is light ... you can attach it to any of the wood members ... the horizontal pieces show nails at ends, so they should be safe to use ... if you can access the back of the wall, then add wood supports in an exact place and use nuts and bolts to attach the TV bracket

Comment: @jsotola The stud you see in the picture is left-most (looking from the opposite side) of 4 studs, and the TV would be mounted on the 2 center studs which are not really accessible at all... Unless I cut a decent sized hole in the drywall. I suppose it has to be done...? The mount came with lag bolts but no anchors or nuts.

Comment: Agree w/ @jsotola -- the tv is pretty light. If you hit two studs with the supplied lags, you'd be great.